# Meta data changing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, app-store, appstore-approval

Please some one help me, my application is in app store it is approved, and released in 16 jan, 2012(ready for sale)  now i want to upload the new version of that application, can I change the application meta data and screen shot, and category etc, is it possible to change the all the information related to the application. Sorry for the incomplete question but I just want to know that can I change the Developer name and app icon also.

Thanks in advance,
Rameshu

Answer (score 2):

You can change those things when submitting a new version of your app.

I believe you can change description and screenshots at any time, but things like category and keywords can only be changed when submitting a new version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to change your app meta data.

When you upload a new version of your app you are allowed to change its meta data until the new version is ready for sale.

Version Number, Primary Category, Secondary Category, Rating, App Name and Keywords are editable only during this period, while other meta data (like Description, Screenshots and Support Email Address) are editable even later.